# Python 3.x requests redirect with unicode character

Tags: python, python-3.x, unicode, character-encoding, python-requests

I am trying to get the following URL with `requests.get()` in Python 3.x: http://www.finanzen.net/suchergebnis.asp?strSuchString=DE0005933931 (this URL consists of a base URL with the search string `DE0005933931`).

The request gets redirected (via HTTP status code 301) to http://www.finanzen.net/etf/ishares_core_dax%AE_ucits_etf_de in a browser (containing the [character 0xAE](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/ae/index.htm) character ® in the URL). Using `requests.get()` with the redirected URL works as well.

When trying to get the search string URL with **Python 2.7** everything works and I get the redirected response, using **Python 3.x** I get the following error:

```
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xae in position 21: invalid start byte
```

The code snippet to test this:

```
import requests

url_1 = 'http://www.finanzen.net/suchergebnis.asp?strSuchString=LU0274208692'
# redirected to http://www.finanzen.net/etf/db_x-trackers_msci_world_index_ucits_etf_1c
url_2 = 'http://www.finanzen.net/suchergebnis.asp?strSuchString=DE0005933931'
# redirected to http://www.finanzen.net/etf/ishares_core_dax%AE_ucits_etf_de

print(requests.get(url_1).status_code)  # working
print(requests.get(url_2).status_code)  # error with Python 3.x
```

Some more information:

- I am working on Windows 7 using Python 3.6.3 with `requests.__version__ = '2.18.4'` but I
  get the same error with other Python versions as well (3.4, 3.5).
- Using other search strings, everything works with Python 3.x as well,
  e.g.
  http://www.finanzen.net/suchergebnis.asp?strSuchString=LU0274208692
- Interestingly I even get an `Internal Server Error` with https://www.hurl.it trying to GET the above mentioned URL. Maybe it is no Python problem.

Any idea, why this is working in Python 2.7 but not in Python 3.x and what I can do about this?

Comment: are you using linux or mac ?

Comment: `requests.get("http://www.finanzen.net/etf/ishares_core_dax%AE_ucits_etf_de")` returns a successful response fore me (`<Response [200]>`), just tested on Python 3.6.3, requests version 2.18.4.

Comment: Yes, this works. Using the search URL does not work, however. I added this to the question.

Comment: I am using Windows 7, added to the question.

Comment: Yes, I can confirm the search URL is returning the same error for me.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The server responds with a URL encoded as Latin-1 which is **not URL encoded**; non-ASCII bytes are shown as `0x??` hex escapes:

```
Location: /etf/ishares_core_dax0xAE_ucits_etf_de
```

The 0xAE byte there is not a valid URL character; the server is violating standards here. What they *should* be sending is

```
Location: /etf/ishares_core_dax%AE_ucits_etf_de
```

or

```
Location: /etf/ishares_core_dax%C2%AE_ucits_etf_de
```

Using escaped data for the Latin-1 or UTF-8 encoding of the URL.

We can patch `requests` to be more robust in the face of this error, by returning the `Location` header unchanged:

```
from requests.sessions import SessionRedirectMixin

def get_redirect_target(
        self, resp, _orig=SessionRedirectMixin.get_redirect_target):
    try:
        return _orig(self, resp)
    except UnicodeDecodeError:
        return resp.headers['location']

SessionRedirectMixin.get_redirect_target = get_redirect_target
```

With this patch applied the redirects work as expected.

I [created a pull request](https://github.com/requests/requests/pull/4372) to improve Location handling.

Comment: The root cause is this design decision here: https://github.com/requests/requests/blob/master/requests/sessions.py#L106-L116

Comment: @Tomalak: and that design is **not wrong**. The server is sending an invalid URL in the location.

Comment: @Tomalak: the design could possibly be more robust however.

Comment: Well it's certainly wonky. You can't simply re-encode a string with your fingers crossed and no error handling whatsoever.

Comment: Thanks @MartijnPieters for the explanation and the patch - it works. Does it makes sense to try to get this into requests itself?