# Python Aiohttp client - disable encoding redirected url

Tags: python, python-requests, urlencode, aiohttp

I'm using aiohttp client to send request to an URL and collecting the redirected URLs.

In my case, the redirected URL contains Unicode text in it. I want it unmodified.

For eg the actual redirected URL is **example.com/förderprojekte-e-v**, but aiohttp client auto encodes it & returns me **example.com/f\udcf6rderprojekte-e-v**.

How to make aiohttp to disable auto encoding of redirected urls.

For requests module, [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47113501/11246868) solution works, but I need help for aiohttp.

My code:

```
async fetch(url):
    #url = 'https://www.example.com/test/123'
    async with client.get(url, allow_redirects = True ) as resp:
        html = await resp.read()
        redir_url = str(resp.url)
        #example.com/f\udcf6rderprojekte-e-v
```

or atleast tell me how to convert **\udcf6** to **ö**

Answer (score 0):

```
async def handle_redirected_url(request):
    # https://
    scheme = request.scheme
    # example.com
    host = request.host
    # /f\udcf6rderprojekte-e-v
    unencoded_path = request.raw_path
    
    unencoded_url = scheme+host+unencoded_path
    return web.json_response(status=200, data={'unencoded_url': unencoded_url)
```

See request object attributes in https://docs.aiohttp.org/en/stable/web_reference.html

Comment: I updated my code in the question. can you explain how your answer works? my question is about aiohttp client, your answer seems like aiohttp server.